# Как начать делать синтаксический разбор?

Tags: члены-предложения

И потому, что изображен великий поэт, чьё любимое время года — осень.

Answer (score 2):

*И потому, что изображен великий поэт, чьё любимое время года — осень.* [потому],(что),(чьё).

Предложение повествоват., невосклицат., сложное, сложноподчинённое, состоит из 3 простых:

1 - главное, представляет собой парцеллированную конструкцию, парцеллят - обстоятельство, выраженное наречием;

2- придаточное причины, двусост., ...;

3-придат. определит., ....